# Sharepoint Model Box Height On Custom Master Page

Tags: master-page, css

We have a custom master page, the orignaly did'nt have this tags in it

```
<div id="s4-workspace">
     <div id="s4-bodyContainer"></div>
</div>
```

However, someone wanted to use the Gnatt chart for project work, so we have had to add them into the master page or the chart fails to work.

The chart now works, but adding these tags seems to have broken the model form used to enter data into a list. The whole hight of the box seems to be only the height of the toolbar at the top, and there are extra scroll bars showing. See below:

[image]

I'm sure there is something missing in the new tags i have created, but i cant work out what is going on

Cheers
Luke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`s4-bodyContainer` needs to wrap the entire content of your masterpage.

Have a look at Randy Drisgill's starter masterpages for examples:

http://startermasterpages.codeplex.com/